# ansible ERROR! conflicting action statements: var, include_tasks

Tags: ansible

Following is my code:

```
- hosts: 11RRvEPG01
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/epg/epg_command.yml
  vars:
    - output: []  
  tasks:
    - name: run epg command
      eric_eccli_command:
        commands: "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{epg_command}}"
      register: command_output

    - name: show execution output
      include_tasks:
        file: /etc/ansible/epg_check_output.yml
      var: 
        output: "{{item.stdout|last}}"
      with_items: "{{command_output.results}}"
```

I got an error message when I ran it:

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: var, include_tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
- name: show execution output
  include_tasks:
    file: /etc/ansible/epg_check_output.yml
  vars: 
    output: "{{ item.stdout|last }}"
  with_items: "{{ command_output.results }}"
```

(change `var` for `vars`)